# Can't share over wifi, only have share over ethernet option

Tags: windows, networking, ad-hoc-network, hotspot

I've been trying to set up a hotspot from my laptop to share my internet connection over WiFi.

However, every time I go to do it I only have the option to share over internet with [connectify](http://www.connectify.me/), but then I get various other errors with other hotspot software such as [mHotspot](http://www.mhotspot.com/) and [Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/).

I also get unexpected errors when trying to set up an Ad Hoc network via the Network & Sharing center. I'm sure everything is turned on (i.e. my network adapter, etc.) I've tried everything to get this to work but I couldn't figure it out.

Running a HP G61-110sa laptop, Windows 7 64 bit, Atheros AR9285 network adapter

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up a `hostednetwork` with the `netsh` command in command prompt. Windows 8 removed the option to set up an ad hoc network, and I've found `netsh` reliable, even if you're using Windows 7.

I believe the exact syntax is `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=[networkname] key=[passphrase] keyUsage=persistent`. That should get you where you need to go. If not, try updating the drivers for your wireless card. (I'm sure you've done it already if you're on here, but I always have to say it.)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not enabled your wireless network adapter.

To resolve this:

- Go to Control panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Change adapter settings.
- Left click on the Wireless network connection and enable it.
- You will find 'share over wifi' after refreshing your connectify.